# attacking the stack

Tags: c, stack

There is a binary file i am working on . It has a function  with the address starting at 123. I need to get my code to execute this function.

Binary file accepts a byte array of size 'n' and does not check for bounds. Entire task is actually to overflow the buffer and cause bad things to happen.

Again, the job is to call address 123 and get it to execute. I was under impression that if a buffer size is , say "4", and i pass 9 characters .., 5 characters will be placed on the stack and executed. (is it true?)

Additionally, in order for me to get to address to be executed, i'd like to say "call 123". From what i understand "call" is "e8", no?

This problem is a bit confusing for me. If someone could help me better understand it, i would very much appreciate it

(Yes, this is a homework question)

Comment: 0xE8 is relative call, and you need to call an absolute address. And stack is usually "floating".

Comment: I wish we had these kind of homeworks..

Comment: Just a bit of curiosity--I would think that a security class like this would have an assembly language prerequisite.  What's up?

Comment: @ruslik: Me too.  They didn't have http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.858/2010/schedule.html back when I was in college.  The first homework assignment of that class is to find and exploit buffer overruns in a web server.

Comment: @Adam It's not the class that surprises me, it's the lack of an x86 assembly language prerequisite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I strongly recommend that you read [Smashing the Stack for Fun and Profit](http://insecure.org/stf/smashstack.html).  It describes in great detail exactly the steps you need to do to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The stack does not contain code, but it does contain the return address for the function. Typical stack structure is:

```
<stack data> <old frame pointer> <return address>
```

`<old frame pointer>` is omitted sometimes and I think would have to for this, so all you have to provide is the data to fill the array then `123`.

Answer (score 0):

A common strategy is to find a `call ESP` opcode in a fixed memory address, and overwrite return address with this address. In this way the execution will continue on the stack. It will work if there is no DEP activated (or supported).

In your case you could also look for an `abs_jump 123` in memory.

EDIT:
@Loren It would work only if stack can be executed. `call esp` has only two bytes opcode, so there is high probability to find it somewhere in memory. The second approach does not execute code from stack, but requires a 5 byte opcode, that is very unlikely to be found.

Comment: Or provide it as part of the data you use to smash the stack.